# What is the command in cmd to count words after a particular word?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, word-count

I am facing the following issue. I am on Windows, using cmd and typing this command `findstr "applications" test.txt`. The result is something like this:

applications:       sample1, guessGame, test1233, testVibeeer, sofiaa

What would be the command to get the number of applications? I have tried with `findstr "applications" test.txt |  find /c /v ""` but it doesn't work. I would like to get a result of 5 in this case but get different result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this command.

```
awk -F "," '{print NF}' test.dat
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Aqeel, the command looks exactly what I need, the only problem is that awk on cmd on Windows doesn't exist

Comment: You can install awk from unix tools for windows from here http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If you want an `awk` command, there are -many- packages available. I have successfully used http://cygwin.com/ and there is the Microsoft WSL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about. That is not to say that this cannot be done with `cmd` or `powershell`, both of which are on all supported `windows` systems.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! Just to ask - when there are no applications, the result is 1, why is that?

Comment: I think, It count the line number if there is no input

Answer (score 1):

use a `for /f` loop to get the relevant line, then count the tokens after the colon with a pure `for` loop:

```
set count=0
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('find "applications" test.txt') do (
  for %%b in (%%a) do set /a count+=1
)
echo %count%
```

(note, `find /c` finds *lines* that contain the search string, so your approach is doomed from the start)

For usage directly on the command line:

```
set count=0
@for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %a in ('find "applications" test.txt') do @for %b in (%a) do @set /a count+=1 >nul
echo %count%
```

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna do it in the most awk-ish of minimalist coding, it's

```
  gawk/nawk  -F, '$+_=NF++'

  mawk/mawk2 -F, 'NF=$_=NF'
```